# Testing an Akka Stream containing a Akka Http cachedHostConnectionPool flow

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka-stream, akka-http

Any ideas on how to best test an Akka Stream containing an Akka Http Flow? I'm struggling with the following method in particular:

```
def akkaHttpFlow(server: String)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer) = {

  val uri = new java.net.URI(server)
  val port: Int = if( uri.getPort != -1) { uri.getPort } else { 80 }

  Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[Seq[String]](uri.getHost, port)
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))

}
```

This is the test code

```
val emails = Set("tonymurphy@example.com")
val source: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source(emails)

val f = source
  .grouped(10)
  .via(requestBuilderFlow)
  .via(akkaHttpFlow)
  .map(responseHandler)
  .runForeach(println)

f.futureValue.shouldBe(Done)
```

It fails with the following error (not unexpected tbh) >>>

```
 The future returned an exception of type: akka.stream.StreamTcpException, with message: Tcp command [Connect(localhost:9001,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed because of Connection refused.
```

Would it be possible to embed akka http server in the test? Or how best could I structure the code to be able to mock it?

The supporting code

```
object MyOperations extends StrictLogging {

  val requestBuilderFunc : Seq[String] => (HttpRequest, Seq[String]) = { emails : Seq[String] =>
    HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = "/subscribers").withEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, ByteString(Json.toJson(emails).toString())) -> emails.toVector
  }

  val requestBuilderFlow : Flow[Seq[String],(HttpRequest, Seq[String]),NotUsed] = Flow[Seq[String]] map requestBuilderFunc

  val responseHandler: ((Try[HttpResponse], Seq[String])) => (HttpResponse, Seq[String]) = {
   case (responseTry, context) =>
     logger.debug(s"Response: $responseTry")
      (responseTry.get, context.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]])
  }
}
```

I have to admit I'm struggling with how to organise my scala applications into objects, traits, classes, higher order functions etc and test them

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is use something like dependency injection to inject a `Flow[(HttpRequest, Seq[String]), (Try[HttpResponse], Seq[String]), Any]`.

In production that flow will be from akka http, but in test you can mock it yourself to return whatever you need.